# PhpStorm and latest Windows 10 updates

Tags: windows-10, phpstorm

I have latest (as at 2 Oct 2016) version on PhpStorm and with the latest Windows 10 updates. I have it complaining about not enough memory (it has 1GB allocated) and starting and stopping with no messages to the screen.

It started 2 days ago with the latest bug updates to Windows 10. I have even re-installed the latest version from their site.

Anybody else experiencing this?

Comment: Check `idea.log` for possible details: https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/articles/206544519-Directories-used-by-the-IDE-to-store-settings-caches-plugins-and-logs

Comment: I'd suggest creating a support ticket, attaching memory dumps (.hprof files) created when PHPStorm runs out of memory

Comment: OK will do. Many thanks!